# C# PrintDocument prints blank page. Why?

Tags: c#

I have the following picture box I populate with a barcode then try to print.

Here's the code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    printDocument1.OriginAtMargins = true;
    printDocument1.DocumentName = "TEST IMAGE PRINTING";

    printDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
    printDialog1.ShowDialog();
    printDocument1.Print();

}


private void printDocument1_PrintPage_1(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    System.Drawing.Graphics formGraphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(picpdf417.Image);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to actually draw the image:

```
private void printDocument1_PrintPage_1(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
  e.Graphics.DrawImage(picpdf417.Image, Point.Empty);
}
```

Comment: You're awesome thanks. Just a follow up quick question. How would you go about printing 2 picture boxes on the same page given certain x and y positions?

Comment: @Vini My sample uses Point.Empty, which is (0, 0).  You would have to measure the first image and adjust the location of the DrawImage for the second image. The "e" variable for PrintPageEventArgs will hold some space information, such as `e.MarginBounds` and `e.PageBounds`, etc.

Comment: K. I've found a way to position the 2 picture boxes on the print document. All I need to do is re-size them according to my coordinates. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Vini If it works to your liking, great.  If not, ask another question and document the code you are using and what the problem is.

Comment: I had a situation where I didn't need it and then things stopped printing so I needed to add this event.